Did Satan physically touch Jesus in the Desert?
We read in Matthew 4 how Jesus was tempted in the desert. First temptation goes like this:

The tempter came to him and said, “If you are the Son of God, tell these stones to become bread.”.


Note the usage 'these stones'. Satan was not pointing to the dusty stones lying somewhere. Most likely, he picked a stone or two, dusted them and placed them in Jesus' hands before making the suggestion (Satan is traditionally  believed to have extended the forbidden fruit to Eve in Eden). In the second and third temptations, we see Satan 'taking' Jesus to places. He was acting friendly with Jesus, and may have guided him with a hand on Jesus' shoulder, just as a person helps a friend climb a hill. At last Jesus says " Get away from me.." implying that Satan was in close proximity. The Gospels do not state in what form Satan tempted Jesus, and in what proximity he was. Are there any apocryphal writings or scholarly views  available on the subject?


It is 'most likely' that the stones referred to were those littering the desert. Anything else is just fanciful and not supported by the text of scripture.

Thanks, Nijel J. If the stones littered  about, and if Jesus did oblige Satan, they would have turned into bread. Would Satan then ask the Son of God to pick bread from the desert ground and eat them ? Hence my suggestion that Satan first put the stones into Jesus'  hand.

.....And Jesus does allow Judas in whom Satan had entered ( Lk 22:3)  to kiss him !

The serpent had hands?

Kris, the fruit being on a tree, may have been too high for Eve. God would not have made the forbidden fruit hanging so low that Eve could easily pluck it. Satan was in the form of Serpent, and could have lowered a branch so that Eve's hand reached the fruit.

..And, the serpent started crawling on the belly after the curse.  Earth scientists say that at least some variety of snakes of ancient times walked on  fours , like the monitor lizard does now.

Did Satan physically touch Jesus in the Desert?
The short answer is no.
Satan being a spiritual being, an angel turned evil, he would be unable to physically touch Jesus in a bodily sense.
Jesus’ ”Temptation in the Desert“ would have been some sort of vision of Satan with Jesus, whether intellectual, imagery or corporal.


Intellectual Visions – The Catholic dictionary defines these as supernatural knowledge in which the mind receives an extraordinary grasp of some revealed truth without the aid of sensible impressions and mystics describe them as intuitions that leave a deep impression.

Imaginary – In Teresa of Avila's The Interior Castle, an imaginary vision is defined as one where nothing is seen or heard by the senses of seeing or hearing, but where the same impression is received that would be produced upon the imagination by the senses if some real object were perceived by them. Niels Christian Hvidt refers to them as visions recognized through mechanisms of the human psyche that are made up of things a soul has acquired through contact with reality.

Corporeal – A supernatural manifestation of an object to the eyes of the body. It may take place in two ways: either a figure really present strikes the retina and there determines the physical phenomenon of the vision, or an agent superior to man directly modifies the visual organ and produces in the composite a sensation equivalent to that which an external object would produce. Underhill refers to this vision type as "little else than an uncontrolled externalization of inward memories, thoughts, or intuitions".


Vision (spirituality)


Thanks, Ken Graham. Could you also explain the term ' corporal vision ' ?
